# Macros: Copying one row with multiple data into many rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using Excel 2010, trying to create a Macro with 3 colunms: test name, expected result and test data.
Test data column has multiple rows, each of the rows have multiple data entries(30)
I wanted to copy the 30 entries from sheet1 to sheet to into multiple rows.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Practice()

    Dim testName As String
    Dim expectedResult As String
    Dim testData As String

    'copying TEST NAME rows to Sheet2
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ' Merging TEST NAME colunm in Sheet2
    With Sheet2
        For counter = 1 To 90
            .Range("A2:A32").Merge
       Next
       testName = counter + 1
    End With

    'copying EXPECTED RESULT to Sheet2
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ' Merging EXPECTED RESULT colunm in Sheet2
    With Sheet2
        For counter = 1 To 90
            .Range("B2:B32").Merge
        Next
        testName = counter + 1
    End With

    ' Copying TEST DATA colunm in Sheet1
    For i = 1 To 30

        Range("C2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("C2:C32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

         i = i + 30

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So A2 is test name, B2 is expected result, C2:AF2 are the test data for row 2 and you have multiple (maybe 90) rows like this?  And you want to put A2 in Sheet2!A2:A31 (merged), B2 in Sheet2!B2:B31 (merged), and C2:AF2 in Sheet2!C2:C31 (transposed from horizontal to vertical)?  And row 3 on Sheet1 would be put into rows 32-61 on Sheet2, etc. for each of the 90 rows on Sheet1?